# Is there any distinction between badges, labels and tags?

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, labels, tags

We are looking at a set of design patterns for helping classification of projects on a list – there seem to be some strong discussions around what the difference is between badges, labels and tags.

My thoughts are, badges (like notifications) are small, usually image-based identifiers, labels are non-interactive identifiers and tags are interactive combinations of the two previous options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Badges are numerical indicators of how many items are associated with an element (a link) and labels are used to provide additional information about something. A tag is a word or a group of words temporarily attached to an item, a SEO tool.

See this explanation on [Atlassian Design Guidelines](https://aui.atlassian.com/aui/latest/docs/badges.html):

> **Badges** provide quick visual identification for numeric values such as tallies and other quantities. They are not used for anything other
> than integers. To call out **tags** or other high-visibility
> attributes, use **Labels**.
> Labels, like mentions and lozenges, are a way of visually tagging UI objects for quick recognition and navigation. They are used in taxonomies (tags) to provide an ad-hoc, user-generated scheme for classification and searching, or in multi-select controls to indicate already locked-in elements.

> Labels can include an action icon (usually 'remove'). Bear in mind
> that they increase the amount of visual noise, particularly in
> combination with other visual tagging elements. They should be short
> and not require line-wrapping.

Comment: Some time ago I edited to fix the broken link. Sad, to see [my improving edit](https://ux.stackexchange.com/revisions/103821/2) rejected/reverted and the link is broken and useless again.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be number of different names associated with this feature. In-order to classify them properly we have to take the functionality in consideration, there are generally 4 types:

1. keywords used for associating data sets
2. show additional information next to UI components
3. numerical value counters
4. UI element used as a call out for new component or feature.

So based on these functionalities the names used out there are:

1. Tag, Chip, Breadbox, Token, navigation Pill
2. Pill, Label, Bubble, Lozenges, Stamp
3. Badge
4. Ribbon, Corner triangle ribbon

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For retail e-commerce context here's my 2 cents

badges
a static piece information that would be appealing to the user

- new arrivals
- free returns/exchange
- cash on delivery
- same day delivery

labels

- care label
- authenticity label e.g. 100% genuine leather

tags
could be associated to price. usually dynamic

- price tag
- discount tag

then again these definitions might loosely be thrown around based on who uses them